# Dual booting my new system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I want to dual boot my system and planning to buy new SSD for that. Should I buy 512 GB SSD or 256GB would be enough ? Also I want the partition to be perfect, like I don't want to run out of storage on my Ubuntu, like if I install Visual Studio Code,how do I choose where it will be installed, and same with every other program ? When I install a new software on Ubuntu does it save itself in `/` or does it go into `/home`. How big should be `/` and is there anyway I can store all large files on HDD. I just my system to boot fast and all the OS kind of stuff should be on SSD and rest I want to put on SSD. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can dual-boot using 256GB or 512 GB.

It's not easy or convenient for a beginner to select where applications will be installed. Most of your "large files" will be data (not applications), and there are many, many tutorials showing how to put data onto a different drive or partition.

Advice: Judging by your intense desire to install Visual Studio and lots of other applications, a larger SSD might work better for you.

Advice: Whichever you choose, START by setting up your good backup regime. The wrong typo in the wrong place can irretrievably destroy all of your data.

Answer (score 1):

It's getting to the point where storage space on SSDs has become so inexpensive that it makes sense to buy a 2TB SSD and put the whole Ubuntu installation on a single ext4 partition on it. With a 2TB SSD there is no need to create a separate /home partition, allowing for flexible and efficient use of disk space.

There are two types of non-NVMe consumer grade SSDs on the market. Low-end consumer grade SSDs are not as fast or power-efficient as higher priced SSDs, but they are cheaper. The warranty period for low-end SSDs is 1-3 years, shorter than the 5 years that many high-end SSDs carry.